# Heroku - Private IP address making requests to server

Tags: python, heroku, server, twisted

In my logs. I'm getting a large number of connections from a local IP address (which changes every time I restart my application. Is this anything to worry about or should I just block internal IPs from making requests to my server

Comment: [sf] would probably be a better place to ask this, it's not a programming issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's because Heroku uses an internal routing system meaning that connections appear to the server as if they had originated from an internal, private ip address